# Passing List object in the glassfish webservice tester

Tags: list, glassfish

There are inputs for all the web service methods each for one argument in the glassfish tester. It's easy to pass integers, strings, etc. but how to pass a List? I'm trying to use java syntax like

```
new List().add(3)
```

but it doesn't work. How is it possible to pass a list object as an argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use serialization in this case so passing serialized list is not a problem - it's just a string.